# How to make a form for this model that will able user to select choice for each question asked - Django

Tags: django, django-forms

Im trying to make a form for a quiz that will able user to select choice for each question when presented, so that when i user submits the form it is saves into the user response. Also how would I list the choices taken from the choice model for each given question?

**what im trying to achieve:**

- display form for each question for a given quiz
- display all on same page as one form
- once all questions answered submit into UserResponse model alongside
  the user that did the quiz

My models seem to work correctly as im able to populate them with data and the relations between them seem to be okay. I am new to django so i have been trying to read the documentation and ive done mutliple tutorials but can seem to find a solution.

Model for quiz:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    active = models.BooleanField('Is active?', default=True, db_index=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPES, default=1, verbose_name='Question Type')
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, unique=False)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Question')

class QuizTakers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class UserResponse(models.Model):
    quiztaker = models.ForeignKey(QuizTakers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response_option = models.ForeignKey(Choice,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can use `ManyToManyField` field to connect all the choices into a `Question` and all the questions into a `Quiz`.
set the `null` option of `ManyToManyField` to `False`, so that If no choices are selected for a queston still the `Question` can be created. And so with the `Quiz`.

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Question(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPES, default=1, verbose_name='Question Type')
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, unique=False)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice, null=True)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    active = models.BooleanField('Is active?', default=True, db_index=True)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, null=True)
```

You can display the `Quiz` by looping it and it's questions and also looping the choices of the questions.

**views.py**

```
def show_quiz(request):
    quizes = Quiz.objects.all()
    quiz = quizes.first() # Select the first quiz
    context = { 'quiz': quiz }
    t = loader.get_template('quiz.html')
    return HttpResponse(request, t.render(context, request))
```

Display Quiz title, description & created date.

**quiz.html**

```
<h1>{{ quiz.title }}</h1>
<h3>{{ quiz.description }}</h3>
<p>Date : {{ quiz.created }}</p>
```

To display questions in a `Quiz` you can do the following:

```
{% for question in quiz.questions.all %}
   <h4>Q{{ forloop.counter }}. : {{ question.question_text }}</h4>
   <p>{{ question.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

To display choices of a `Question` you can do the following:

```
{% for choice in question.choices.all %}
   {{ forloop.counter }} {{ choice.choice_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is useful thanks! I was unsure to use many to many or foreign key to be honest. Another question I have then is how would I allow the user to update the database when they select a choice for each question? Because right now it will just display them if im not mistaken, I want them to be able to select the choices and then submit at the end. Thanks in advance1

Comment: For the selecting purpose you have to use radio buttons or checkboxes and then when user clicks the submit button submit that whole quiz form and do the reading in view or instead of that you can use django ModelForm or just a form to create the quiz form.

Comment: okay thanks, i am still a little confused as to how im supposed to produce a form that will submit these results into the UserResponse model so that i have a db of each user and results of their questions and answers